# How to Cascade 3 Tables in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have 3 tables:

Supplier {s#, Sname, status, city}
primary key {S#}

part {p#, pname, color, city}
primary key {p#}

job {j#, jname,city}
primary key {j#}

I inserted some record's into supplier, part and job with "insert all"

now I want to create table spj {s#, p#, j#, quantity} which the first three columns are foreign keys.

how can I insert Records into spj Table?

sample table data:

supplier:
[image]

part:
[image]

job:
[image]

Comment: mysql <> sql... Pick one!

Comment: MySQL <> Oracle...

Comment: Show us some sample table data for the 3 existing tables, and what you want in the new table. Perhaps you should create a view instead of another table.

Comment: but mysql uses sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Oracle command creates table `spj` as carthesian product of three tables and adds random quantities. If you don't want random values - change to null.

```
create table spj as 
  select s.sid, p.pid, j.jid, round(dbms_random.value(1, 100)) quantity
    from supplier s cross join part p cross join job j;
```

If you created table already use `insert`, not `create`. Instead of `cross join` you could use any join condition, maybe `city`. Now we got 9 x 9 x 9 rows.

And here I'm adding foreign keys:

```
alter table spj add constraint spj_sup_fk  foreign key (sid) references supplier (sid);

alter table spj add constraint spj_part_fk foreign key (pid) references part (pid);

alter table spj add constraint spj_job_fk  foreign key (jid) references job (jid);
```